# Adding 2 jquery scripts in the same page... 1 on 2 work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to put together 2 Jquery scripts on the same page but can't get both working at the same time. There is always a bug of some sort. Could you tell me if you can do this?

All I'm looking for is a blank HTML page with 2 inputs, one with the [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) and the other with [timepickr](http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/#s-downloads).

I'm really not that good with javascript, so if someone could help me it would be awsome. Both links give like 2-6 files to include, js and css and I do not know which one to include so that they don't interfere with one another. I want the minimal implementation of both.

My latest try was this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/development-bundle/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">  
<link rel="Stylesheet" media="screen" href="js/ui-timepickr/src/css/ui.timepickr.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui-timepickr/page/jquery.utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui-timepickr/page/jquery.strings.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui-timepickr/page/jquery.anchorHandler.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui-timepickr/page/jquery.ui.all.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui-timepickr/src/ui.timepickr.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>    

    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

        $('#ATTRIBUT_38').timepickr({
               convention:24,
               rangeMin: ['05','10','15','20','25','30','35','40','45','50','55'],
               rangeHour24: [$.range(8, 12), $.range(12, 21)],
               prefix: ['Avant-midi','AprÃ¨s-midi & SoirÃ©e'],
               suffix: ['Avant-midi','AprÃ¨s-midi & SoirÃ©e']
             });

    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="demo">

Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">
<input id="ATTRIBUT_38" type="text" value="02:30">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show what have u tried so far?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but an alternative if all you want is date and time. http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: _What_ are the bugs you're experiencing?

Comment: On your question's formatting: the easiest way to get big blocks of code to format correctly is to paste in your code, select what you pasted, and then click the "Code sample" button that's at the top of the editor (it looks like two curly braces `{}`).

Comment: basically, only one... or the other is working, but not both at the same time. It's not really a bug, it's more like I files are probably calling the same functions or I'm calling extra css/js that I shouldnt. It's just that I don't really understand js... thanks

Comment: Thanks john for that, I was looking for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with timepickr and jQuery UI exists since jQuery UI 1.8 and was reported already in April 2010. It seems there is no official bugfix yet :-( but here is a hack that might work: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-utils/issues/detail?id=48#c4 
Anyway, I'd recommend to use an alternative TimePicker (e.g. as already proposed by Tim above)

Comment: Thanks K232, it explains why I've wasted a full day on this... I was not a fan of http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ but after playing with it, it has so much options it could be a very good alternative. The problem is that I find the "time" picker clumsy. I'd rather see all my hours as hovering boxes and all my min as hovering boxes. It's a lot quicker and user friendly. Just like in the script i'm trying to implement. Thanks ALL for your help